# Notice: Undefined property: In creating new model using namespace

Tags: php, function, return-value

I am a newbie php coder. I have this main controller:

```
namespace App\Core;

class Controller
{
    /** @var View View The view object */
    public $View;
    public $templates;
    /**
     * Construct the (base) controller. This happens when a real controller is constructed, like in
    */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function loadModel() {

        $this->model = new \App\Front\Model\IndexModel(); //error line

    }
}
```

In IndexController I have:

```
namespace App\Front\Controller;

use App\Front\Model\IndexModel;

class IndexController extends \App\Core\Controller {

    public function index(){
        $this->loadModel->test();
    }
}
```

In IndexModel I have:

```
namespace App\Front\Model;

class IndexModel
{

    public function test(){

        echo 'test print';

    }
}
```

In Action I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: App\Front\Controller\IndexController::$loadModel in /Applications/xampp/htdocs/cmstest/application/Front/Controller/IndexController.php on line 13

I load all classes using composer and PDR-4 method.

What is the problem and how do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: `Controller::loadModel` is a method not a property so, `$this->loadModel->test();` should be `$this->loadModel()->test();`

Comment: @CD001: I change this But see error:`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function test() on null in /Applications/xammp/htdocs/cmstest/application/Front/Controller/IndexController.php:13`

Comment: `loadModel()` needs to return the `IndexModel` you've just assigned to `$this->model` - e.g. `public function loadModel() { $this->model = new \App\Front\Model\IndexModel(); return $this->model }` If you don't return anything, it's `NULL`

Comment: @harmonytalk - did my post answer you?

Comment: @DavidWinder: Sure. u see my comment below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in your `loadModel` method you just assign the new model to `this` but you not returning anything -> so you cannot can function `test()` on null.

In order to fix it use:

```
class IndexController extends \App\Core\Controller {
    public function index(){
        $this->loadModel();
        $this->model->test();
    }
}
```

If you **insist** on doing in `index` only one function you can modify your `loadModel` function to:

```
public function loadModel() {
    if (!$this->model) // that way you load the Model only once. If you want to reload every time just remove the if
        $this->model = new \App\Front\Model\IndexModel();
    return $this->model;
}
```

And then you can do:

```
public function index(){
    $this->loadModel()->test();
}
```

Comment: this worked. My way is true and good for load two object in `IndexController`?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you mean to "load" = set 2 property in the loadModel()` function?

Comment: @DavidWinder: my mean separate two `$this->loadModel(); $this->model->test();`

Comment: If you mean to call 2 different function then yes

Comment: @DavidWinder:Your mean Yes: Good Or bad ?! Any way for call one function?!

Comment: I meant it Good practice. You can also change `loadModel` function to `getModel` and return a Model and reduce it to 1 call but I believe the way I answer it is more simpler. I will update my answer with a way to do it with my line

Comment: @DavidWinder: thanks. In advance mode(after edit for load dynamic model) This function load all model need to controller ie: usermodel - notemodel - loginmodel into UserController - NoteController - LoginController